# Writing 2^x in PL

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

We designed a PL that has the following syntaxes:

```
load variableName, value
inc variableName //increases the value by 1
loop variableName //loops it a certain number of times depending
                    on variableName's value at the time. Also if
                    variableName's value is somehow altered later
                    on in the code, the loop cycle runs the same
                    amount as variableName's default value.
end //we put this to as a corresponding end to our loop.
```

For example here is a simple code that computes x+x:

```
VM vm6 = new VM();
            vm6.add("load x, 7");
            vm6.add("load answer, 0");
            vm6.add("loop x");
            vm6.add("inc answer");
            vm6.add("inc answer");
            vm6.add("end");
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to write 2^x but am stuck on this for the longest time. Could someone help me?

EDIT: I actually figured it out. I used my own solution of nested loops.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: in Java it's simply `1 << x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pretty straightforward, doesn't it? TO compute X^Y, You loop Y times, each time you multiply the answer by X. The answer starts off being 1 (anything to the zero power is 1).

```
load x, 2
load answer, 1
loop [power]
[multiply procedure]
end
```

The `[multiply procedure]` referred to above is the additive method of multiplication. Two numbers multiplied together (`x * y`) are equal to the number of intersections between two loops of length `x` and `y`. So for your purposes, multiplying `x * y` looks like this:

```
load x, [x value]
load y, [y value]
load answer, 0
loop x
loop y
inc answer
end
end
```

So your whole 2^x procedure is just a series of loops:

```
load x, [power]
load base, 2
load answer, 1
loop x
    load addition, 0 //reset the multiplier
    loop answer
        loop base
            inc addition
        end
    end
    load answer, addition // load answer with multiplied value
end
```

Of course, if you can't do nested loops, you're pretty much out of luck.